# How does interconnection of paintings in Hogwarts work?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Is there any explanation about how the paintings are connected, so that people can walk from one painting to another? How can these imprints of dead people be transferred between paintings? If imprints can be moved away from their painting (frame as physical object), can they be bound to other objects as well (which are not paintings)? Must they be moved by a wizard/witch or is there a space (in another dimension) that connects them?

Comment: A wizard did it

Comment: Hi Daniel. I closed your question as it seems to be covered by the linked question. If you think that it is not you can [edit] your question to explain why.